# "Серая зона" между числами в боте дискорд

Tags: python, бот, discord

Столкнулся с проблемой, что хотел сделать шанс. Вроде всё нормально сделал, но в ходе тестов понял, что у меня между рандомными числами есть "серая зона", где шанс так сказать нулевой. Как мне это исправить? Вот кусок кода:

```
if message.content == "/card":
            randomcrd = random.randint(1,100)
            if randomcrd >= 90:
                await message.channel.send(f"Тебе выпала карта!")
                await message.channel.send(embed=embedClsCrd)
            elif randomcrd <= 10:
                await message.channel.send(f"Тебе выпала карта!")
                await message.channel.send(embed=embedMadCrd)
```

Comment: Чтото я ничего не понял

Comment: Ну. Между 90 и 10 в коде просто ничего нет. Просто не отправляется ничего

Comment: Так в коде ж написано - если число БОЛЬШЕ 90, то одно, а если число МЕНЬШЕ 10, то другое. А что делать, если выпало число между 10 и 90 - не написано.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В чём тогда смысл ставить random.randint(1,100), если вы не используйте 80% чисел, сделайте так:

```
if message.content == "/card":
        randomcrd = random.randint(1,20)
        if randomcrd > 10:
            await message.channel.send(f"Тебе выпала карта!")
            await message.channel.send(embed=embedClsCrd)
        elif randomcrd <= 10:
            await message.channel.send(f"Тебе выпала карта!")
            await message.channel.send(embed=embedMadCrd)
```

Comment: Если выпадет 10, то это будет слепая зона

Comment: Исправил, что условие от 1 до 10 и от 11 до 20

Comment: Спасибо огромное!